# Is there a way to identify which docs in Google Drive have scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there a way to run a script against Google Drive to identify which docs and spreadsheets, etc. have Google Apps Scripts associated with them?

I have thousands of documents and spreadsheets, many with scripts.  I want to identify all the files with scripts in them so that I can audit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible through scripts but you can go to your Google Account security page to see which documents / sheets have additional access to various services. These files are more likely to have scripts associated with them.

Link: https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: Not perfect, but better than nothing.  Thanks for your help.